# Terminate/Stop maven test when running from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, jenkins, testng, terminate

I am using plugin as below :

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

When I run POM.xml as maven test, even I terminate process from eclipse/jenkins, it didn't get stop.

Comment: Strange. You're using the big red button on the _Console_ view? It should terminate the process. Which maven plugin are you using, m2e? Which version?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am using m2e (1.4.0.20130601-......) & m2e-wtp(1.0.1.20130911......)

Answer (score 2):

Referring to bottom of page to the below link :
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html

You need to turn off forkmode, by adding forkcount to configuration in plugin

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.17</version>
<configuration>
   <forkCount>0</forkCount>
   <suiteXmlFiles>
         <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
   </suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
```